# XML ElementTree with pretty print

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, pretty-print

1.) if you look at the following tags and the spaces of my xml-output you will notice that the spaces are not that correct, cause of the code in 2.)

- `<SD-ID-Gesamt>` & `</SD-ID-Gesamt>`
- `<Lage>` & `</Lage>`
- `<Parameter>` & `</Parameter>`

Current output:

```xml
<SD-ID-Gesart>
    <SD-ID-Code>
        <SD-ID>DD-RE-1.0G-10</SD-ID>
        <Lage>
            <XP>14.84</XP>
            <YP>73.19</YP>
            <ZP>7.92</ZP>
            <WKS>95.32</WKS>
            </Lage>
        <Parameter>
            <Form>Rectangle</Form>
            <Art>Deckendurchbruch/Art>
            <Gewerk>-HT-SAN-DURCHBRUCH</Gewerk>
            <Ebene>1.OG OKFF +4,50 m</Ebene>
            <Breite>1,800000</Breite>
            <Höhe>0,500000</Höhe>
            <Tiefe>0,450000</Tiefe>
            <Status_Neu>0</Status_Neu>
            <Status_Geändert>1</Status_Geändert>
            </Parameter>
    <SD-ID-Code>
```

---

2.) I am calling `indent()` to pretty print my xml-files. It is working almost as wished, except from one little mistake in the code you see below. The mistake you can see in the xml-output in the picture above.

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
i = "\n" + level*"  "
if len(elem):
    if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
        elem.text = i + ""
    if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
        elem.tail = i
for elem in elem:
    indent(elem, level+1)
    if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
        elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

---

3.) with the code you see next i create the ElementTree, when it went through `indent()`.

```
indent(sd)
tree = ET.ElementTree(sd)
tree.write(open(pfad + '\\'+ datei_name + '.xml', "w"), encoding='utf-8', 
xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
```

---

I need to edit the definition of the `indent()` indent function to get the spaces correct. In that case I really have no idea how to put back the spaces when the tag is equal. I would be very very happy if you could help me getting that fixed.

Comment: Can you use third-party packages? Python's `lxml` maintains a *pretty_print* handler.

Comment: just to install all the requirements of lxml to get it run is way too much in my eyes. The pip-install wasnt enough in my case to pretty-print my xml-files. I would really like to give lxml a try but for my work the workaround with the indent is enough for me.

Comment: If you use XML extensively, this is a great library to have in your toolkit being a full-featured DOM library equipped with XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0. If on Windows, install via [binary extensions](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) (download .whl, and then pip install /path/to/whl).

Comment: My other answer is to use XSLT (either via `lxml` or [external processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) called by Python via `subprocess`), which has an indent handler and run the Identity Transform. I don't recommend treating XML as a text file. Happy coding!

Comment: Can I contact you in future, when I am up to install the library? I failed once already trying to install..

Comment: Are you on Windows? Did you go through the binary extensions route as commented above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: See [xml.etree.ElementTree.indent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) as of Python 3.9.

I couldn't reproduce the bad indentation from your example, but according to http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint, your function is mis-copied.  For these lines:

```
if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
    elem.text = i + ""
```

There should be two space between the quotes:

```
if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
  elem.text = i + "  "
```

I ran this code and it displays properly.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

def indent(elem, level=0):
  i = "\n" + level*"  "
  if len(elem):
    if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
      elem.text = i + "  "
    if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
      elem.tail = i
    for e in elem:
      indent(e, level+1)
    if not e.tail or not e.tail.strip():
      e.tail = i
  else:
    if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
      elem.tail = i

data = '''<one><two><three>3</three><four>4</four></two></one>'''
tree = et.fromstring(data)
indent(tree)
et.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```
<one>
  <two>
    <three>3</three>
    <four>4</four>
  </two>
</one>
```

Notes for future:

- Images of text can't be copied so I leave it as an exercise for you to test on your own XML.
- Cut-n-paste *exact* code and input data *as text* to reproduce the issue to make it easy for answers to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you a lot! The mistake was the line 12 of "else:...". There was one tabstop too much. Thank you very much !

Comment: @N0VO No problem. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Sry bro.. I did now. I am a big noob on stackoverflow :)

Comment: pylint complains about the for loop reusing elem -- do you think that is intentional or a mistake?  The next if statement uses the new value.

Comment: @rrauenza It appears to be intentional.  The effbot.org site is giving an "on hiatus" message at the moment to verify, but I've changed the code to work without the pylint error.

Comment: Nowadays, ElementTree has a built-in `indent()` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent

Comment: @mzjn I see it was added (finally) in Python 3.9.